# Android relative layout align center of background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I have a background image, which is simply colored panel such as silver purple, etc.,

This background image is set as `andorid:background` of `RelativeLayout`, which consist of a `ImageView`

I want that imageview's image resource to be appear like in center of the background image.

I tried `alignParentTop` and `marginTop` to position the combo image in center.

It works as expected, but when trying on different devices, as `marginTop` is hardcoded such as 10dp,, or 5dp, the alignment looks differently on different devices with different resolution.

I have even created various dimens.xml files for various configuration with various marginTop dp values. Still it only works on specific devices and doing fro all devices is obviously impossible. So i need to set or align the background and foreground images such that foreground image is centered over background image.

**Note**: Using Framelayout is not of my concern. I want this by RelativeLayout.

Comment: try this property for the background image android:layout_centerInParent="true"

Answer (score 1):

On the `ImageView` and the parent `RelativeLayout`, remove all of the padding and margin stuff you have, then add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to the `ImageView`. If you know the height and width of the image in the `ImageView`beforehand, set the `ImageView` to match it identically (in dp's). Otherwise, try setting the ImageView height and width to `wrap_content` and potentially `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`.

Comment: The purpose of adjustViewBounds?

Comment: More as a precaution, may not be necessary - depending on how and when you're setting your Image (or image resource) to the ImageView, the ImageView may not resize both it's height and width, it may end up actually being larger (either taller or wider) than the image. Truth be told it may not affect the apparent centering as you'll end up (again depending on how you assign the image to the imageview), with equal space around the image. Set a background color for the imageview to see if it's actually larger than the image you've assigned.